# IE9 Rendering Twitter Bootstrap in Quirks 5.5 mode

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in my html5.Master file for my C# ASP.NET pages using Twitter Bootstrap.  Still some pages are rendered by IE 9 in Quirks 5.5 mode.  Is there anything else that can be done to get them to render correctly and print correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
      <link href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap.css?v=2")%>" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/docs.css?v=2")%>" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/prettify.css?v=2")%>" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/print.css?v=2")%>" />

      <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>      window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/scripts/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>

    <!--[if IE 6]>    
        <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: It could be invalid HTML. Find one of the pages that is being rendered in quirks mode and run it through an HTML validator.

Comment: What does ASP.NET actually end up rendering?

Comment: Source code that is rendered: http://www.sourcepod.com/lzltbu74-11831